# How to use Microsoft.Extensions.LoggingLogger in a scoped service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging

In a .Net 5 Web API, I'm trying to do logging in a scoped service.

I first tried to introduce the logger service via constructor dependency injection:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public class SmsService : ISmsService
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public SmsService(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

But when I run the API, I get this exception:

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be
> constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor
> 'ServiceType: PropWorx.API.Interfaces.ISmsService Lifetime: Scoped
> ImplementationType: PropWorx.API.Services.SmsService': Unable to
> resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger' while
> attempting to activate 'PropWorx.API.Services.SmsService'.)'

I then removed the dependency injection, and tried creating a scope at the point of logging:

```
private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    using (var logger = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger>())
    {
        logger.LogError("some error message");
    }
}
```

But I get this compile time error:

> CS1674    'ILogger': type used in a using statement must be implicitly
> convertible to 'System.IDisposable'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### About your first try

The code seems legitimate. My guess is that you are not configuring the DI container with a concrete implementation of the `ILogger` so by the instantiation time, it does not know which object of `ILogger` type to create.

You can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to see how to configure and add the default logging providers.

#### About your second try

The following is the definition of [GetRequiredService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceproviderserviceextensions.getrequiredservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceProviderServiceExtensions_GetRequiredService__1_System_IServiceProvider_)

```
public static T GetRequiredService<T> (this IServiceProvider provider);
```

You can see that it returns the `T`, in your case the `ILogger` interface. The created instance is not Disposable, so it can't be used in the using declaration.

Try using it this way:

```
using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    var logger = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger>();
    logger.LogError("some error message");

}
```

Please provide the injection configuration for `ILogger` (meaning the definition where you provide the concrete implementation of `ILogger` you are using, to help you with the first example.

Comment: Thanks - you were right on both counts. Regarding DI, instead of private readonly ILogger _logger; I used private readonly ILogger<SmsService> _logger; and the error went away. Regarding your second suggestion, I tried that and it also worked. Thank you! :)